# OpenCV STIP (space time interest points)

Tags: opencv, action, keypoint

Where can I get the source code of Laptev's STIP (space-time interest points)? On his webpage only the executables are provided.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If he didn't make them public, they are not public. However, you can implement the algorithm using the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering if anyone else has already implemented it and made it available (obviously I have already searched for it on the Internet, but without success so far).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the sources were made public at some point, or so I believe.

You can find an old version [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~rmessing/uradl/stip-velocityFeatures.zip):  (plus other stuff regarding the paper of the guy hosting it...)

The code is hideous, by the way.